# Delete null values from 2d JSON

Tags: python, json

I have a 2 dimentional json which looks like this:

```
a =  [
   {
    "photo": null,
    ....
    "webUrl": null,
    "createdByUser": null,
    "lastModifiedByUser": null,
    "id": "154854566458484754...."
    },
    {
    "photo": null,
    ....
    "webUrl": null,
    "createdByUser": null,
    "lastModifiedByUser": null,
    "id": "154854566458484000...."
  },
 ]
```

how can I remove all null values with the help of python ?

For a one-dimensional Json I get it like this:

```
filtered_data = {}
for key, value in data.items():
    if value != None:
        filtered_data[key] = value
```

but for more two-dimensional Json json I don't get it quite right

```
   filtered_data = {}
   list          = []

    i = 0
    length = len(data) 
    for i  in range(0, length):
        for key, value in data[i].items():
            if value != None and key != '@odata.type':
                filtered_data[key] = value
        list.append(filtered_data) 

    return list
```

so I get several times the last entry of the json

Comment: You need to reinitialize `filtered_data` for each iteration of  `for i  in range(0, length):`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how can I remove all null values with the help of python ?

The idea is to scan the data and collect `not None` values.
Try the below

```
import json

json_str = '''[
   {
    "photo": null,
    "webUrl": null,
    "createdByUser": null,
    "lastModifiedByUser": null,
    "id": "154854566458484754...."
    },
    {
    "photo": null,
    "webUrl": null,
    "createdByUser": null,
    "lastModifiedByUser": null,
    "id": "154854566458484000...."
  }
 ]'''
data = json.loads(json_str)
new_data = []
for entry in data:
    new_data.append({})
    for k, v in entry.items():
        if v is not None:
            new_data[-1][k] = v
print(new_data)
```

output

```
[{'id': '154854566458484754....'}, {'id': '154854566458484000....'}]
```